# ls -l listing directory list

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell

Any idea why there are different output . Some of which are misleading

```
-bash-4.2$ mkdir -p new_dir/sub_dir/under_dir
-bash-4.2$ touch new_dir/sub_dir/under_dir/file.txt
-bash-4.2$
-bash-4.2$ ls -rlt
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 3 kony kony 4096 Oct 21 20:53 new_dir
-bash-4.2$
-bash-4.2$
-bash-4.2$ ls -rlt *
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 3 kony kony 4096 Oct 21 20:53 sub_dir
-bash-4.2$
-bash-4.2$
-bash-4.2$
-bash-4.2$ ls -rltd
drwxrwxr-x 3 kony kony 4096 Oct 21 20:53 .
-bash-4.2$
-bash-4.2$
-bash-4.2$ ls -rltd *
drwxrwxr-x 3 kony kony 4096 Oct 21 20:53 new_dir
-bash-4.2$
-bash-4.2$
-bash-4.2$
-bash-4.2$ ls -rtlR
.:
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 3 kony kony 4096 Oct 21 20:53 new_dir

./new_dir:
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 3 kony kony 4096 Oct 21 20:53 sub_dir

./new_dir/sub_dir:
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 2 kony kony 4096 Oct 21 20:53 under_dir

./new_dir/sub_dir/under_dir:
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kony kony 0 Oct 21 20:53 file.txt
-bash-4.2$
-bash-4.2$
-bash-4.2$
-bash-4.2$
-bash-4.2$ ls -rltR *
new_dir:
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 3 kony kony 4096 Oct 21 20:53 sub_dir

new_dir/sub_dir:
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 2 kony kony 4096 Oct 21 20:53 under_dir

new_dir/sub_dir/under_dir:
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kony kony 0 Oct 21 20:53 file.txt
-bash-4.2$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what output you expected nor what is misleading to you. You got different output because you provided different input each time.

Relevant facts:

- `ls` without operands works as if the only operand was `.`. Note `-rltd` and such are options, not operands.
- Normally if the operand is a directory, `ls` will print entries in the directory. This is a special treatment because in most cases (if the operand is a regular file, special file, fifo, …) `ls` just prints information about the operand.
- `-d` disables this special behavior for directories.
- `-R` makes `ls` recursively list subdirectories encountered.
- `*` in your examples was expanded by your shell before `ls` was even started. `*` expands to all entries in the current working directory with names not beginning with `.`. Apparently in your case there was just one matching entry in the current directory: `new_dir`.

These are commands you typed, I gathered them for readability:

```
ls -rlt
ls -rlt *
ls -rltd
ls -rltd *
ls -rltR
ls -rltR *
```

These are what you really run, after expansion by the shell; respectively:

```
ls -rlt
ls -rlt new_dir
ls -rltd
ls -rltd new_dir
ls -rltR
ls -rltR new_dir
```

These are equivalent commands with explicit operands; respectively:

```
ls -rlt .
ls -rlt new_dir
ls -rltd .
ls -rltd new_dir
ls -rltR .
ls -rltR new_dir
```

And these are descriptive queries (common options `-rlt` not explained, because I understand they are not the issue):

- `ls -rlt .` – what is inside `.`?
- `ls -rlt new_dir` – what is inside `new_dir`?
- `ls -rltd .` – what is `.`?
- `ls -rltd new_dir` – what is `new_dir`?
- `ls -rltR .` – what is inside `.` and every subdirectory encountered?
- `ls -rltR new_dir` – what is inside `new_dir` and every subdirectory encountered?

You got answers to these queries. The queries are different, so are the answers.